# Uncaught TypeError when trying to replace "var" with "let"

Tags: javascript

I get this error for the code snippet below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined
```

I am trying to use "let" to declare a variable. So there is no way of taking advantage of hoisting. If I declare the function after the variable declaration, again another issue will raise. Please let me know what to do?

```
<img id="imgMine" src = img.png> 
<script>
let myImg;
function explosion (){
    myImg.src = "";//**<-- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined**
}
myImg= document.getElementById("imgMine").onclick = explosion();
</script>
```

Comment: `.onclick = explosion`, no parentheses. You need to assign the function, not its return value.

Comment: Notwithstanding the other errors, using `.onclick` is the 1990's way of attaching an event handler.   Look into `.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned the return value of `explosion()` to `myImg` (and to `document.getElementById("imgMine").onclick`, but that isn't really relevent).

`explosion` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Hence "Cannot set property 'src' of undefined".

This has **absolutely** nothing to do with using `let` instead of `var`.

---

It looks like you are trying to set the `src` property of the image element. If you want to do that, then you need to assign **the image element** to the variable.

```
myImg = document.getElementById("imgMine");
```

---

It also looks like you want to assign the `explode` function as the click event listener. To do that you need to assign the **function** itself and not the result of **calling** the function. Lose the `()`.

```
myImg.onclick = explode;
```

Or you could use the modern idiom:

```
myImg.addEventListener("click", explode);
```

---

That said, an image is not designed to be an interactive control. While you can add a click event handler to it, it won't show up as clickable in assistive technology (like a screen reader) or be navigable to without a pointing device (many people tab through the interactive elements in a page).

In short, what you are doing is highly **inaccessible** (which could cause you legal problems).

You should use an element designed to be clicked on, like a button.

```js
let myImg;

function explosion() {
  myImg.querySelector("img").src = "";
}

myImg = document.getElementById("imgMine");
myImg.addEventListener("click", explosion);
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="imgMine"><img src="https://placeimg.com/200/100/tech"></button>
```